# The probability of selecting both defective items when taking 10 out of 24

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following is a problem from my probability text.

A box contains 24 light bulbs, of which two are defective. If a person selects 10 bulbs at random, without replacement, what is the probability that both defective bulbs will be selected.

My first step was to calculate the size of the sample space which is comprised of all 10-tuples selected from 24 bulbs or,

$$ {24 \choose 10} $$

I am having trouble finding the size of the event where both defective bulbs will be selected. The answer key suggests that the number of subsets that contain the two defective bulbs is the number of subsets of size 8 out of the other 22 bulbs or

$$ {22 \choose 8} $$

I can't seem to wrap my head around why this is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I want to know who found out there were 2 defective light bulbs, and why they put them back into the box of good bulbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A selection of $10$ bulbs, in which both defective bulbs are selected, consists of selecting eight of the twenty-two good bulbs and both of the two defective bulbs, which can be done in $$\binom{22}{8}\binom{2}{2} = \binom{22}{8} \cdot 1 = \binom{22}{8}$$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that of the $10$  selected balls, two are defective. That means, the remaining $8$ are non-defective. In how many ways can you select $8$ balls from $22$ non-defective balls?

Answer (score 1):

I assume all light bulbs are different (otherwise the number of ways to select the good ones is just 1).

Your solution is correct because the order doesn't matter. You simply 'fix' the 2 defective ones in the sample and select 8 out the remaining items.